# HTML Title on Google contains image alt text

Tags: html, google-search

I have a strange situation with my website where whenever it appears on Google Search, the alt text of one of the images is also displayed despite not being part of the `<title>` tag.

On my website (sparen.github.io), I have the following header:

```
    <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type">
    <title>Andrew Fan's Code Dump: The Embodiment of Code and Hacks (AFCDTECH)</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="blah.css">
    <meta content="Andrew Fan's Code Dump: The Embodiment of Code and Hacks (AFCDTECH)"
      name="description">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Sparen, Touhou, Danmakufu, ph3, Tutorial, Script, Project">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">
  <script>
  <!-- Removed Google Analytics stuff for purposes of StackOverflow Question-->
  </script>
  </head>
  <body id="mhome">
    <div class="yui-t1" id="top">
      <center><a href="http://sparen.github.io"><img alt="&quot;Site Logo&quot;" src="images/logo.png" style="width:90%"></a></center>
```

However, in Google Search, the title appears as follows:
[image: Google]

***This is actually a different page, but all pages on my website seem to have the same issue, and all have the same header structure.

I don't know why it has that extra 'Site Logo' thing, which only appears as part of the image alt text in my banner (which is not even in the head but rather the body of the page).

It hasn't disappeared in the past few months, and it'd be nice to know if there's something I never took into consideration when originally building my website or if there's something BlueGriffon did before I migrated away from it.

Answer (score 0):

Google seems to be confused by your quotes inside the alt text. Just remove them or use

```
<img alt='"Site Logo"' src="images/logo.png" style="width:90%">
```

Am I wrong or this could be a flaw (vulnerability?) in Google Search?

Comment: I really don't actually know - BlueGriffon added the quotes. I'll try removing the &quot; and see if that fixes anything.

Comment: The w3 validator states that my site (the affected parts) are compliant, and now Google Search seems to shove text from completely different files into the search entry titles now that the quotes are gone. I guess that either I've done something very wrong or there is some sort of vulnerability. I've been fixing everything over the past few months, and it still acts weird.